# Escaping line break in csv php

Tags: php, csv

I have a .csv template I'd wish for people to fill up, save it and upload it.

The problem is this, assuming some users would insert hidden line breaks in a row, when using fgetcsv() it would output the row broken by the hidden line breaks.

How can I escape the line break or sanitize my data?

Possible solution:

assume first row is correct, $count = count the number of delimiters until line break, the rebuild the text into an array as long as $count;

but i think the're better options available.

**LATER EDIT**

Here's the input *IMPORTANT[ ! ] : the data inside the excel file is "fine", it isn't broken, it's a single row!!! saving it as a csv file and opening it in notepad shows the following

```
asd;"asd
asd
asd";asd;asd
```

Here's the code

```
$handle = fopen("file.csv","r");
$data = fgetcsv($handle,";");
while($data = fgetcsv($handle)) {
    $array = explode(";",$data[0]);
    print_r($array);
}
fclose($handle);
```

Here's the echoed data

```
Array ( [0] => asd [1] => "asd ) Array ( [0] => asd ) Array ( [0] => asd" [1] => asd [2] => asd [3] => )
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "hidden line"?

Comment: open an excel file and type in something, then press alt+enter then type in more stuff

Comment: @christi ...then save this file in csv format and read it with fgetcsv(). Surprised? Where are all your imaginary broken rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is very easy to test your case and see that there are no broken rows, if fields being properly *quoted*.

So, a CSV line like this

```
1,"joe
""Big Coyote""
Hopkins",598600
```

will be read with not a single problem.

Comment: let's say i'd make a scrips that follows some predictable patterns, but i'm expecting that my users might submit wrong data, so i'd like to remove line breaks inside rows, i'll try to figure it out by my own, thanks for the lecture

Comment: and finally modified my script, and it finally works while($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,';','"')) print_r($data); i might apologize for not making my problem clear enough but everything i read on php.net and I couldn't really figure it out.